# How to properly install ethernet card

Tags: motherboard, ethernet, pci-express

I picked up a PCIe ethernet card because my ethernet port stopped working. I got [this ethernet card](http://www.hiroinc.com/product_details.php?item_id=61). I have the [following motherboard](http://www.gigabyte.com/products/product-page.aspx?pid=3423#ov).

I'm having trouble figuring out how to plug it in. My motherboard has 2 PCIex16 slots (the blue slots in the image). The first one (furthest to the right) has a video card in it.

Answer (score 0):

Your motherboard has also 2 PCI Express X1 ports so you can plug the network card in one of them. What's so hard about it?

Comment: are those the small slots next to the x16 slots? one of them is blocked by the video card and the other one is not close enough to the back slot of my case

Comment: What do you mean, not close enough? The slots are positioned according to the ATX standard. Any ATX case that can house this motherboard can also support every slot.

Comment: take a picture and post it above. Depending on your gfx card, size of the fans on the gfx card.... it might be a tight fit or you can move the gfx card unless you have two gfx cards

Comment: @Logman The X1 port on the right should always work even with 2 graphics cards.